# Why <div class="clear"></div> is used after multiple floating DIVS in a container DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have encountered a `<div class="clear"></div>` at many places, but I am not aware why is it done? Can someone brief me on this, why it is used in css? This is the CSS:

```
div.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: More about this go to this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The height of an element is determined by its child elements (unless it is explicitly set). E.g.:

```
+------A------+
|+-----------+|
||     B     ||
|+-----------+|
|+-----------+|
||     C     ||
|+-----------+|
+-------------+
```

The height of A is determined by where the lower border of its child C is.

Now, floating elements do not count towards the height of their parents, they're taken out of the regular flow:

```
+------A------+
+--+---------++
   |    B    |
   +---------+
   +---------+
   |    C    |
   +---------+
```

The A element is collapsed to a minimal height, because its two children are floated.

Clearing elements are introduced to restore the correct height:

```
+------A------+
|  +---------+|
|  |    B    ||
|  +---------+|
|  +---------+|
|  |    C    ||
|  +---------+|
|+-----D-----+|
+-------------+
```

The D element is a zero-height element with the `clear` attribute set. That causes it to fall below the floated elements (it *clears* them). That causes A to have a regular child element to calculate its height by. That's the most typical use case at least.

The often better solution to introducing extra HTML elements is to set A to `overflow: hidden` though. That has the effect of forcing a height calculation, which has the same effect of growing the height to the desired size. This solution may or may not have other side effects though.

Comment: Can you please explain further how "set[ting] A to `overflow: hidden`" helps? Isn't A's height *already* being calculated to exclude the heights of B and C because they float? How does hiding them because they overflow A's bounding box force the box to grow to include them? I also dislike adding invisible *content* to control *layout* and want to understand this better (IMHO) solution.

Comment: @David Maybe I didn't put it in the best terms. As far as I can explain, the `overflow` rule means that content needs to be `hidden` if and only if there really is no way for it to fit in the box. That causes the box to first try to actually fit around the content before giving up and actually hiding it. Only if there are other constraints given (e.g. `height`) which would cause the box to be unable to accommodate the content will it have to `hide` the overflowing content.

Answer (score 1):

It is to clear out floating styles.

clear: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear

float: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float

Comment: Didn't think those were too bad of explanations. Changed links to w3c.org :)

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, it's like telling the browser to not allow anything (i.e., any element be it a div, span, anchor, table etc) either on the left or on the right of the previous element. This will make the next element move to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Good explaination by deceze. But `<div class="clear"></div>` is old method and unprofessional try using

```css
#anyelement:after {
  display: block;
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just keep adding other elements which needs to cleared like `#firstlement:after, .secondelement:after` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The Most common problems we face when we write the code with float based layouts is that the parent div container doesn't expand to the height of the child floating elements. The typical solution to fix this is by adding an element with clear float after the floating elements or adding a clearfix to the parent div.

I am giving you some two good examples for better understanding about clearing floats :-

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

All technical details has been introduced above. More generally this kind of element serves as 'hard line' for floated elements, laying them properly vertically one under another. It's worth to say that there are better methods these days.

Comment: Does this answer add materially different value that the other five answers lack?